# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.security.negotiation.NegotiationAuthenticator

Tags: security, authentication, jboss, classnotfoundexception, spnego

While deploying webapp on JBOSS EAP 6.1, I am receiving following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.security.negotiation.NegotiationAuthenticator from [Module "deployment.dummy.ear.dummy-web.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:197) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:443) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:431) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:373) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:118) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WarDeploymentProcessor.getInstance(WarDeploymentProcessor.java:407)
        ... 8 more
```

We are using SPNEGO authentication and jboss-web.xml is configured as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web>
    <context-root>dummy</context-root>
    <security-domain>SPNEGO</security-domain>
    <valve>
        <class-name>org.jboss.security.negotiation.NegotiationAuthenticator</class-name>
    </valve>
    <jacc-star-role-allow>true</jacc-star-role-allow>
</jboss-web>
```

I found reference to similar question on [RedHat portal](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/348993). But its unanswered. Can you please tell me how to resolve this issue? Please let me know, if you require more information.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add in `WEB-INF/jboss-deployment-structure.xml` the next dependency:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="org.jboss.security.negotiation" />
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

See also: https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/DRAFTUsingJBossNegotiationOnAS7 and https://github.com/kwart/spnego-demo

I hope this help.

Comment: I had done the same. But I guess some extra spaces were left or something else. I copied contents from your answer and it worked fine. Marked your answer! Thanks.